# reproducing a tensor matrix with eigen library

Tags: c++, matlab, eigen

I'm facing a little problem. I'm translating a program from matlab/octave to C++. This progam is dealing with some matrix manipulation. I want to reproduce this : in matlab/octave we can define a matrix like :

```
      matrix = zeros(10,25,360);
```

and I get a matrix with 10 rows, 25 columns and a "depth" of 360. I want to reproduce the same thing in C++ using Eigen.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3):

There are [unsupported Modules](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/unsupported/index.html) for Eigen which let you define [tensors](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/unsupported/classEigen_1_1Tensor.html). With those modules you can translate your problem into C++.

Comment: thank you a lot for your answer. I'm trying to use it. I download the last version of Eigen when I include the unsupported part dealing with Tensor, I get the following error : 'This file requires compiler and library support for the \
ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be \
enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
#endif
'

Comment: Did you add those compiler options as CXXFLAGS ? Which compiler are you using?

Comment: thank you for your answer. I'm using GNU GCC Compiler but I don't know how to add this options to my compiler. I use code::blocks as an IDE under windows 7. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The current Eigen tensor module is extremely limited feature wise. You can't even add the coefficients of 2 tensors together! I have been using [the tensor code in this fork of Eigen](http://code.bsteiner.info/eigen/src) instead. It adds support for coefficient wise operations, convolutions, contractions, and recently morphing primitives such as slicing. Moreover it can take advantage of GPUs to speed things up which was the big selling point for me.

There is a [pending pull request](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/pull-request/68/tensor-support/diff) so hopefully it will make its way into the main Eigen code base soon.

Comment: Anybody wondering: "pending pull request: 'Merge already done.'"